# How to use the Pomodoro Timer in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

I haven't used the Pomodoro timer in Spacemacs before.

How can I start the timer?

There is the `org` configuration layer already present in my Spacemacs config. Is there anything else that I need to add?

Comment: `SPC m p` is what I found.but this is undefined in  my spacemacs .

Comment: [Installation](https://github.com/lolownia/org-pomodoro) all done?

Comment: @AniMenon I think I have all installed.maybe I need to add a task by orgmode before I start a pomodoro clock?

Comment: After add the layer `org` in config file,open a org file,then type `SPC m p` can activate a pomodoro clock.This is really easy,but really useful for me.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/pomodoro).

Answer (score 4):

1. Enter into agenda `C-c a a`
2. Select a item
3. Start a pomodoro clock `SPC m C p`

Answer (score 3):

You and Ani Menon have answered your question: You can use Pomodoro in org-mode (that is - editing an org file) if you have installed [org-pomodoro](http://github.com/lolownia/org-pomodoro) and there must be at least one [TODO](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html) in the file.